# prevent default to stop too fast clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.Arrow').click(function(){
    runFunc(); 
});
```

runFunc have multiple fadeOut and fadeIn to change images, if the user click too fast, some element forward faster and become inconsistent. I tried to prevent double click like

```
$("*").dblclick(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

but it doesn't solved my problem. I tried on and off the click event but I have to put the runFunc within the handler, so I can't bind the click event.

Assume runFunc is a image slider, how to prevent click too fast on the left and right arrows?

Comment: What you want is something like [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs#debounce)

Comment: add `e.preventDefault()` on your click event.